# Combining a thread_pool with a deadline_timer - issues with template (time)

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I have integrated Boost's asio service and used it in conjunction with a thread pool.

Having created a thread pool which handles both futures and async tasks, I am wanting to expand it a bit further to handle deadline timers too (anti-pattern?).  Unfortunately, I am hitting my limit in comprehension of handling templated code.  To be more precise, I would like to pass a boost::posix_time (ex: boost::posix_time::milliseconds(100) or boost::posix_time::seconds(5) ), but I am struggling to understand how I could make this possible.

The partial listing of code below is the current implementation of my thread pool.

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class thread_pool
{
public:

    // ...
    // Other boring stuff here...


    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    template<class Task>
    void enqueue_async(Task task)
    {
        m_pIO->post( std::bind(&thread_pool::wrap_task, this,
                                                  std::function< void() >( task )));
    }

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // NOTE: Needing help here - 'expiry_time' should be relative.
    template <class Task, class ???>
    void enqueue_deadline_async(Task task, const ??? & expiry_time)
    {
        const std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::basic_deadline_timer<???> > apTimer = std::make_shared<boost::asio::deadline_timer>(*get_service_pointer(), expiry_time);
        apTimer->async_wait(std::bind(&thread_pool::enqueue_async, this, task));
    }

private:

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    void wrap_task( std::function< void() > task )
    {
        try
        {
            task();
        }
        catch (const std::exception &e)
        {
            // Todo: Log that there is a problem!!
            BOOST_ASSERT_MSG(0,e.what());
        }
    }

};
```

Up until this point, I have been using the enqueue_task(...) to queue an asynchronous task for processing by the thread pool. I would now like to expand the thread pool to be able to asynchronously call a callback parameter to a deadline timer (see enqueue_deadline_async()) BUT let the thread pool handle the task.

The reason to integrate the thread_pool with a deadline_time is to:

- Minimize the number of io_services running concurrently in code.
- Prevent a deadline_time from blocking the io_service too long - decrease the impact on other pending timers.

Finally, are my nested calls in the io_service dangerous?

Environment Configuration:

- Ubuntu v17.04 (Zesty) x86_x64
- Boost v1.63
- GCC 6.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things,

```
template <class Task, class ???>
void enqueue_deadline_async(Task task, const ??? & expiry_time)
```

Since it's a deducible template argument, just name it something, and you're done

```
template <class Task, class T>
void enqueue_deadline_async(Task task, const T & expiry_time)
```

Next up:

```
const std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::basic_deadline_timer<???> > apTimer = std::make_shared<boost::asio::deadline_timer>(*get_service_pointer(), expiry_time);
```

First off, `boost::asio::deadline_timer` already allows what you want in the question. So don't muck with `basic_deadline_timer`. Secondly, the shared pointer needs to be convertible to the type of `apTimer` anyways, making it even less useful (because picking another chrono clock model would not even compile).

### Solution

Just use the interface that deadline_timer also uses:

```
template <class Task>
void enqueue_deadline_async(Task task, const boost::posix_time::time_duration& expiry_time)
```

It works:

```
int main() {
    thread_pool tp;
    tp.enqueue_deadline_async([]{ }, boost::posix_time::seconds(5));
    tp.enqueue_deadline_async([]{ }, boost::posix_time::milliseconds(5));
}
```

Comment: Can you provide any documentation? A google search of `boost enqueue_deadline_async` comes up only with this answer (spread around multiple websites from webdata crawlers) which makes me question the legitimacy of this answer.

Comment: @searchengine27 I think you misunderstood what was "claimed". The question was about how to accept a time duration. The suggestion was to use `boost::posix_time::time_duration` exactly what is used [in the interface of `deadline_timer`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_deadline_timer/expires_from_now/overload3.html) - proof http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/829d4d9c8460769e (put another way: `enqueue_deadline_async` is just OP's own function, as you can see in his question code)

Comment: well looks like my vote is locked in now anyway (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80762/why-do-votes-get-locked). This is why I don't like SO.

Comment: @searchengine27 Nobody made you vote :) I don't mind so, cheers!